# MONTH Variable now having issue

Tags: batch-file, variables, windows-10

I have used a simple batch file to create a daily modified archives of working files. I have used it for years on going back to Windows 2000 probably thru Windows 2008 R2. I just started using it on my Windows 10 desktop in Sept of 2019 as well but I just recently noticed something must have changed in Windows 10 that is causing my Month output folder to have 2 extra, seemingly invalid characters after the month name which is causing me some issues in Windows.

My code is this

```
@echo off
color 06

set FILE_DATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
set YEAR=%date:~10,4%

REM Month Converter From Date Variable
SET MONTH=%DATE:~4,2% 
SET MONTH=%MONTH:01=01 January% 
SET MONTH=%MONTH:02=02 February%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:03=03 March%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:04=04 April%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:05=05 May%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:06=06 June%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:07=07 July%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:08=08 August%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:09=09 September%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:10=10 October%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:11=11 November%
SET MONTH=%MONTH:12=12 December%

ROBOCOPY "D:\Josh\Documents" "D:\Josh\Archives\%YEAR%\%MONTH%\%FILE_DATE%\Documents" /r:0 /w:0 /s /MAXAGE:1 /XF *.arb *.arf *.u$r *.db *.tmp *.prn *.uas *.pst
```

Which should create a folder structure like

```
D:\Josh\Archives\2019\09 September\09-18-2019
```

but what it looks to be outputting is

```
D:\Josh\Archives\2019\09 September  \09-18-2019
```

If I go to rename the folder, you can see the 2 characters space in the name.

[Rename Space (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll3sd.jpg)

If I backspace to remove the characters from the folder name, I get this error.

[Can't Rename (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdmkI.jpg)

If I try to delete the folder I receive this error.

[Can't Find Error (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey5Rr.jpg)

If I move the contents of the month folder to another folder things get really weird and adjacent folders start having issue as well, including files disappearing. Anywho it's a pretty serious issue.

This same script still runs fine on Windows Server R2. I have been digging thru online trying to find out if something in the way the variables or Robocopy may have changed that might be causing it but I am guessing it's just something I need to tweak in the code for a changed in Windows 10 but I can't seem to find a solution. Hoping a veteran can point me in the right direction. Thanks for your time!

p.s. - The images are addressing different folders, I did this post over a period of time, but the condition is the same. Thx :)

Comment: `SET MONTH=%MONTH:01=01 January% ` There is an extra space at the end.

Comment: To keep trailing spaces from being assigned as a value to your variable use this best practice for all variable assignments: `SET "MONTH=%MONTH:01=01 January%"` Surround the assignment in quotes.

Comment: This can easily be done much simpler by combining some `powershell` to your `batch-file`. Consider: `for /f "tokens=1-4*" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format 'MM MMMM dd yyyy'}"') do echo %%i %%j %%k %%l` where you can then instead of echo, assign the metavariables as: `set "Year=%%l"`, `set "shortMM=%%i"` `set Month=%%j` and finally, `set "day=%%k"`

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. Looks like I maybe don't have enough rep yet to vote for my accepted answer as I don't see an option, or maybe you can mark a comment as an answer?  Squashman hit the nail on the head for me. Thanks Squashman!  Squashman used to be a nickname of mine back in the day in high school. :)

Annnnd my comment is too long...

Comment: ...

dxiv -Thanks I did have an extra space at the end of January!


Gerhard - I have only dabbled in PS so that's lookin like gibberish to this noob right now, but I will look into parsing thru it and maybe get it figured out as an alternative for the future. Thank you!

If I can get my rep up in time, I will try to remember to come back and mark as answers. Kind of a weird thing not being able to mark your own question as answered?

Comment: 1. There is not much more to do, I gave you the command, you can copy it into a batch file and see how it works. 2. There are no answers to mark as correct as non was posted, only comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're aware, but `%DATE%` is local/language dependent, so its output cannot be relied upon to provide consistent output in an expected format.

Here's an example of a simple methodology which uses two `for` loops to generate your date based variables irrespective of your user, PC, locale, or language, settings.

```vb
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Color 06
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In ('"%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L | %__APPDIR__%find.exe " 123""') Do Set "Today=%%H-%%I-%%G"
For /F "Tokens=%Today:~,2%" %%G In ("January February March April May June July August September October November December") Do Set "Month=%Today:~,2% %%G" 
"%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe" "D:\Josh\Documents" "D:\Josh\Archives\%Today:~-4%\%Month%\%Today%\Documents" /MaxAge:1 /R:0 /S /W:0 /XF *.arb *.arf *.u$r *.db *.tmp *.prn *.uas *.pst
```

If you wanted to try it with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), here's a basic one line example to get you started:

```
@PowerShell.exe -NoProfile "Robocopy.exe \"D:\Josh\Documents\" \"D:\Josh\Archives\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy\\MM MMMM\\MM-dd-yyyy')\Documents\" /r:0 /w:0 /s /MAXAGE:1 /XF *.arb *.arf *.u$r *.db *.tmp *.prn *.uas *.pst"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your current `robocopy` command as is, and simply using `powershell` to determine the month for date format without manually specifying each month manually.

```
@echo off & color 06
for /f "tokens=1-4*" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format 'yyyy MM MMMM dd'}"') do (
   robocopy "D:\Josh\Documents" "D:\Josh\Archives\%%i\%%j %%k\%%j-%%l-%%i\Documents" /r:0 /w:0 /s /MAXAGE:1 /XF *.arb *.arf *.u$r *.db *.tmp *.prn *.uas *.pst
)
```